# Circuit or component to detect temperature change

Tags: heat, thermistor, coil, thermal-cutoff

I know this is a very simple question but I didn't find the answer. I have very less knowledge in electrical.

I want a component or a circuit or whatever, which I can attach to a heating coil so that after a specific temperature threshold, the supply should get cut off.

Ex. Suppose I am applying 120V to a resistive coil. Now it will start heating from 0 temperature (degrees) to higher... I want the supply to be cut off when the coil heats up to say 100 degree celcius.

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a thermostat is what you're after? There's a lot of pre-made ones around and it's probably safest to use one off-the-shelf when 120V is involved.

Comment: There are various options in bimetallic thermostats. After it cuts off, do you want it to: (a) reconnect the power when the heater cools down? (b) wait until someone resets it by pressing a button? (c) keep the power disconnected until a repairman fixes something?

Comment: Thank you brian
I want to wait for the button to be pressed to resume the supply

Answer (score 3):

I think a bimettalic element, a start switch and a relay is what you need. The relay will use one of its contacts to short the switch so that after pressing the switch, the relay becomes latched and powers the heating element. The bimettalic strip will disconnect  the relay coil when temperature is reached. You can only reactivate providing the temperature has dropped below the bimettalic switch's lower threshold AND you press the switch.

[image]